# Cambiar Fuente a varios Labels al mismo Tiempo, C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, recursión, fuentes

Quiero cambiar la fuente a los labels (Label1 al Label10) al mismo tiempo, explico:

Tengo un Formulario `WindowsForms` en el cual tengo un `panel` dentro de ese panel tengo agregados 2 controles de usuarios `UserControls`, dentro de ambos `UserControls` tengo varios `labels`, que no pertenecen a los `UserControls` sino que están encima de los `UserControl` agregados en ellos desde el formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Esta imagen para ilustrar, El `Panel` es el `Gris Oscuro` de fondo, los UserControl contienen 1 icono y un título que pertenece al control de usuario incluido la parte del color de fondo gris claro. Los únicos objetoss que no pertenecen a los controles de usuario son los labels internos que se pueden observar.

Pero al ejecutar la función también cambia la fuente a los títulos de los `UserControls` que también son Labels pero no pertenecen al formulario como tal, sino que vienen del UserControl, lo hago de esta manera, con una **función recursiva**:

```
private void cambiar_fuentes(Control contenedor)
{
    foreach (Control control in contenedor.Controls)
    {
        if (control.Controls.Count > 0)
           cambiar_fuentes(control);
        else
        {
           if (control is Label) ((Label)control ).Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
        }
   }
}
```

> Llamando la función:

```
cambiar_fuentes(panel1);
```

**¿Cómo puedo cambiar solo la fuente solo de los labels (1 al 10) que pertenenen al formulario como tal?**

**EDITADA**

**Fragmento de Código del Designer.cs:**

```
        this.panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.panel1.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
        this.panel1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.flowLayoutPanel1);
        this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, 1);
        this.panel1.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(295, 2);
        this.panel1.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(2, 732);
        this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
        this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(295, 732);
        this.panel1.TabIndex = 5;

         this.flowLayoutPanel1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)));
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.userControl1);
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.userControl2);
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = System.Windows.Forms.FlowDirection.TopDown;
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, 34);
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.Name = "flowLayoutPanel1";
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 684);
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 29;
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.WrapContents = false;

        this.userControl1.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.userControl1.Controls.Add(this.label2);
```

> Aquí `this.uersControl1.Controls.Add(this.label1);` continúan los demas labels...

Entorno: Visual Studio 2010 & .NET Netframework 4.

Comment: Puedo sugerir agregar una excepción en tu else donde excluyas en base a las propiedades del contenedor (en este caso el usercontrol), ya sea el nombre (si nomas son esos 2) o bien con reflexión

Comment: Para el ejemplo solo ilustre 2 user controls, pero son mas, si no mal interpreto tu comentario propones una solución semejante a la de: `Andres` , la cual probé pero no me ha funcionado. El excluir los UserControl en la función no esta recorriendo los labels que contiene aunque no pertenezcan a usercontrol. **¿Cómo lo hago usando reflexión?**

Comment: Podrías agregar un prefijo a los nombres de los `labels` de tipo título, por ejemplo, 'lblTituloXXX'. Ya en tu método recursivo no consideras los controles con dicho nombre o prefijo.

Comment: Habría que ver el código del UserControl. Creo que lo mejor sería que expusieras una propiedad (por ejemplo `LabelsFont` o `ItemsFont`) que te permitiera cambiar la fuente de esos elementos específicos. O que expusieras los labels a través de una propiedad diferente a `Controls`.

Comment: @AsierVillanueva el código  de mi `UserControl` es bastante amplio y si, tengo una propiedad expuesta para cambiar la `Fuente` del `Label` que se encuentra en el Titulo, me caería bien la opción sobre: `ItemsFont` pero **¿Cómo hago eso?** _tomando en cuenta que la cantidad de Items puede variar, es decir, un `UserControl` puede contener mas `Labels` que otro_. Me he guiado de [este UserControl](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JohannGranados.CollapsiblePanelforWindowsForms) para realizar el mio, solo que agregando funciones adicionales y exponiendo mas propiedades.

Comment: @Davlio sería un poco complejo, ya que tendría  que preguntar por cada título con ese prefijo, y no solo son dos títulos, son muchos más, entonces sería preguntar uno por uno, estaría bien si fueran pocos.

Comment: @AsierVillanueva se me ha presentado un problema semejante [Aqui lo explico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/150993/69447) y no han podido ayudarme, como usted entendió la estructura por favor puede revisarlo para sugerirme una idea? si no es mucha molestia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrías crear una propiedad de sólo lectura en tu `UserControl` que devuelva la lista de controles añadidos a éste. Sin incluir los propios del control de usuario.

Según el código del control en el que te has basado vendría a ser algo así

```
 public IEnumerable<Control> PanelControls
{
    get
    {
        var panelControls = new List<Control>();
        foreach (Control control in Controls)
        {
            if (control != titlePanel) panelControls.Add(control);
        }
        return panelControls;
    }
}
```

De esta forma la propiedad `PanelControls` únicamente devuelve los controles añadidos al control de usuario no los propios y podrías recorrerlos e ir cambiando la fuente o cualquier otra propiedad que desees.

El método `cambiar_fuentes` lo podrías cambiar por un método genérico en el que le indiques el tipo de control al que quieres aplicarle el cambio, y le pases la fuente:

```
private void CambiarFuentes<T>(IEnumerable<Control> controls, Font newFont) where T: Control
{
    var controlList = controls as Control[] ?? controls.ToArray();
    if (!controlList.Any()) return;
    foreach (var toChangeControl in controlList.OfType<T>())
    {
        toChangeControl.Font = newFont;
    }
    CambiarFuentes<T>(controlList.SelectMany(x => x.Controls.OfType<Control>()), newFont);
}
```

De esta forma para cambiar todas las fuentes de los Labels incluidos en los controles `CollapsiblePanel` podrías hacer:

```
foreach (var collapsiblePanel in Controls.OfType<CollapsiblePanel>())
{
    CambiarFuentes<Label>(collapsiblePanel.PanelControls, new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular));
}
```

Si prefieres mantener el formato actual puedes comprobar en el método `cambiar_fuentes` si el control contenedor es un control de tipo `CollapsiblePanel`. Si es así recorres la colección `PanelControls` y si no la colección `Controls`:

```
private void cambiar_fuentes(Control contenedor)
{
    var panel = contenedor as CollapsiblePanel;
    var controlList = panel != null
        ? panel.PanelControls
        : contenedor.Controls.OfType<Control>();
    foreach (Control control in controlList)
    {
        if (control.Controls.Count > 0)
            cambiar_fuentes(control);
        else
        {
            if (control is Label) ((Label)control).Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
        }
    }
}
```

De esta forma podrías seguir haciendo la misma llamada:

```
cambiar_fuentes(panel1);
```

Comment: Bien ya lo he agregado a mi `UserControl`, pero ¿De qué modo accedo ahora para cambiar las fuentes?  , cómo utilizo mi función : `cambiar_fuentes(Control contenedor)` con este método que me contestó. ¿Puede editar la pregunta y colocarr como hacerlo?

Comment: Lo hago asi: `foreach (Control control in userControl1.PanelControls)
            {
                if (control is Label) ((Label)control ).Font = new Font("Arial", 30, FontStyle.Regular);
            }` , pero no me funciona aun, **¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?**

Comment: He ampliado la respuesta para mostrar cómo podrías aplicar la propiedad

Comment: He utilizado el método Genérico cuando ejecuto el método el `foreach` nunca entra a esta linea: `CambiarFuentes<Label>(collapsiblePanel.PanelControls, new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular));`   luego intento probar el otro método original, pero esto tiene sintaxis incorrecta `var controlList = contenedor is CollapsiblePanel panel
        ? panel.PanelControls
        : contenedor.Controls.OfType<Control>();` ¿Tiene algo que ver con que use el VS 2010 y NetFramework 4?

Comment: Para utilizar el método genérico en tu caso seguramente tengas que modificar el `foreach` para coger los controles de `panel1`: `foreach (var collapsiblePanel in panel1.Controls.OfType<CollapsiblePanel>())`. En cuanto al error de sintaxis ¿qué error te da exactamente?

Comment: En esta [imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eWCY.png) se muestra que sucede con el código,  en su método esta linea `is CollapsiblePanel` mi control esta en una carpeta del proyecto llamada `Controles` y el userControl se llama `MenuExpandible` como puede observar en la imagen, pero no me deja declarar esa linea como plantea en su método. Disculpe la tardanza me ocupé.

Comment: Vale. Es muy posible que esa sintaxis no estuviese disponible aún en la versión de C# de Visual Studio 2010. La he modificado por otra equivalente.

Comment: Saludos, se me ha presentado un problema semejante [Aqui lo explico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/150993/69447) y no han podido ayudarme, como usted entendió la estructura por favor puede revisarlo para sugerirme una idea? si no es mucha molestia.

Answer (score 3):

Se me ocurre que podrías discriminar los usercontrols cuando evalúas si el control tiene controles internos de la siguiente manera:

```
private void cambiar_fuentes(Control contenedor)
{
    foreach (Control control in contenedor.Controls)
    {
        if (control.Controls.Count > 0 && !(control is usercontrol))
           cambiar_fuentes(control);
        else
        {
           if (control is Label) ((Label)control ).Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
        }
   }
}
```

Ten en cuenta que tienes que sustituir `usercontrol` por el nombre de la clase de tu control de usuario.

De esta manera evitas que se inspeccionen los controles de usuario.

Comment: La he probado pero no me funciona, Aunque los Labels no pertenecen directamente a los `UserControls` en el formulario estan agregados en ellos, y si se excluyen no  esta recorriendo los labels en la función.

Answer (score 3):

Hola puedes hacer los siguiente
Recuperar de un control, en este caso tu  formulario aquellos de tipo `Label` de la siguiente forma

```
private void cambiar_fuentes(Control contenedor)
{
  foreach (var c in contenedor.Controls.OfType<Label>())
  {
    c.Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular);

  } 
}
```

Luego lo llamarías así en tu formulario

```
cambiar_fuentes(this);
```

Comment: Hola Sergio, lo he probado pero no me funciona, no puedo enviarle por parámetro `this` porque me tomaría todos los labels del formulario, solo le envío el `panel` que necesito, pero no me funciona tu solución :(

Comment: Pues pasa el panel: `cambiar_fuentes (this.Panel1);`

Comment: Si de esa forma lo he hecho, pero no funciona, tu solución no esta mal, pero para mi caso especifico no funciona.

Comment: De todas formas, mi método no es recursivo, solo recoge la colección ` Controls` de ese formulario. A un primer nivel

Comment: Si comprendo, tu método funcionaria perfecto si no están los `UserControls`. por eso acudí a la recursividad, pero aun asi no me funciona como quiero.

Comment: Para que me quede claro. `label1`,  `label2` por ejemplo, están incluidos dentro de `usercontrol1`?

Comment: Estan Incluidos (Arrastrados encima del control desde el formulario), pero NO pertenecen como tal al `Usercontrol1` , mira [esta imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Itdmz.png) ese es el `UserControl` solo contiene eso que vez, y una vez agrego el `usercontrol1` al `formulario`, le colo los Labels arriba.

Comment: Por lo tanto tu función nunca entra a esta linea: `c.Font = new Font("Arial", 60, FontStyle.Regular);`

Comment: Hola. Los `label` están incluidos en algún otro contenedor dentro del `panel`? Si fuera así tendrías que usar el método : `cambiar_fuentes(this.Panel1.OtroContenedor);`

Comment: Puedes ver la jerarquía de tus controles desde Visual Studio. `View > Other Windows > Document Outline`

Comment: Hay otro contenedor que es un: `flowLayoutPanel1` pero esta sentencia no es válida: `cambiar_fuentes(this.Panel1.flowLayoutPanel1);` , esa es la única jerarquía.

Comment: Además lo he probado asi: `foreach (var c in panel1.Controls.OfType<Label>())` y así: `foreach (var c in flowLayoutpanel1.Controls.OfType<Label>())` pero igual nunca entra a recorrer esta fila: `c.Font = new Font("Arial", 60, FontStyle.Regular);`

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta mostrando el código de tu Designer.cs de tu formulario?