# ¿Cómo Recorrer opciones de menú y mostrar/ocultar opciones según los permisos del usuario?, C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy realizando la validación de acceso a los menú del sistema según los permisos que tenga el usuario logeado. En este caso NO estoy utilizando los menú convencionales `MenuStrip` y `TreeView`, si no que estoy usando un tipo de menú creado con un `UserControl` y para los items `LinkLabel`.

**Este es el [Menu (User Control)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JohannGranados.CollapsiblePanelforWindowsForms) que he tomado como base para realizar los menú.**

En la Base de datos contengo varias tablas con los menu del sistema y los diferentes permisos ahora me veo en la necesidad de mostrar/ocultar las opciones `LinkLabel` segun corresponda.

> Tengo que Recorrer los Menú Principales, luego las Categorías y luego los Items que pertenecen a la categoría.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He hecho lo siguiente para recorrerlos, y de este modo puedo obtener acceso a los menú principales, las categorias y los items, pero necesito recorrerlos con un ciclo individual:

```
string menu_principal = string.Empty, categoria_menu = string.Empty,
           item_menu = string.Empty, comando = string.Empty;

private void FormMenu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      recorrerOpcionesMenu<LinkLabel>(flowLPrincipal.Controls.OfType<Controles.MenuExpandible>());
}

private void recorrerOpcionesMenu<T>(IEnumerable<Control> controlMenu) where T : Control
{
      var lista_opciones = controlMenu as Control[] ?? controlMenu.ToArray();

      if (!lista_opciones.Any()) return;

      foreach (var menu in lista_opciones.OfType<T>())
      {
           menu_principal = menu.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name;
           categoria_menu = menu.Parent.Parent.Name;
           item_menu = menu.Name;

           if (administrador == "S")
               comando = "select ...."; 
           else
               comando = @"select ...."; 

           try
           {
              DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
              //dataset = ..... ejecutar el  comando y asignarlo al dataset....
              if (dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
              {
                  existe = true;
                  menu.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Visible = true;
                  menu.Parent.Parent.Visible = true;
                  menu.Visible = true;
              }

              if (existe)
                  existe = false;
              else
              {
                  menu.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Visible = false;
                  menu.Parent.Parent.Visible = false;
                  menu.Visible = false;
              }
          }
          catch (SqlException excepcion)
          {
                MessageBox.Show("Ha ocurrido un error: \n\n" + excepcion.Message,
                                    "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
          }
      }

      recorrerOpcionesMenu<T>(lista_opciones.SelectMany(objeto => objeto.Controls.OfType<Control>()));
}
```

Lo ideal sería recorrerlo de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además al User control `MenuExpandible` he agrego este método para obtener los controles que este contiene agregados:

```
public IEnumerable<Control> ControlesAgregados
{
    get
    {
        var _controles_agregados = new List<Control>();
        foreach (Control control in Controls)
        {
            if (control != titlePanel) _controles_agregados.Add(control);
        }
        return _controles_agregados;
    }
}
```

El cual podría usarlo de esta manera:

```
foreach (var panel_plegable in this.flowLPrincipal.Controls.OfType<Controles.MenuExpandible>())
{
   recorrerOpcionesMenu<LinkLabel>(panel_plegable.ControlesAgregados);
}
```

> **NOTA** Esto: "Controles.MenuExpandible" `Contoles` es una carpeta y `MenuExpandible` es el User Control. Estoy usando los `flowLayoutPanel` para que al momento de ocultar los items, estos se acomoden automáticamente en la posición correspondiente.

Espero que puedan darme una idea de como solucionarlo; Saludos!

Comment: No termino de entender tu problema... :/

Comment: @gbianchi necesito recorrer el menú con 3 ciclos, ejemplo el primero recorre los menu principales (Modulo1, modulo2..) el segundo debe recorrer las categorias (Mantenimiento, Procesos, reportes) el tercer ciclo debe recorrer los items (mantenimiento1, mant2.., proceso 1, proceso2..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizás la pregunta no fue lo suficientemente clara, pero he solucionado el problema de la siguiente manera, Basado en la Jerarquía actual debo recorrer los elementos en 3 ciclos.

> - Ciclo 1 - Los Menus Principales (Modulo1, Modulo2, Modulo3,...)
> - Ciclo 2 - Las Categorias (Mantenimientos, Procesos, Reportes...)
> - Ciclo 3 - Los Items (Mantenimiento1, Mant2, proce1....)

Para ello cree los siguientes vectores para  asignar la cantidad de elementos a recorre:

```
Controles.MenuExpandible[] menus_principales;
Controles.MenuExpandible[] categorias_menu;
LinkLabel[] items;
FlowLayoutPanel[] flowLayout1;
FlowLayoutPanel[] flowLayout2;

menus_principales = flowLPrincipal.Controls.OfType<Controles.MenuExpandible>().ToArray();
```

Para recorrer la jerarquía de los controles y acceder a todas las propiedades del control que se interese en usar, mediante el uso de ciclos `for` así:

```
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < menus_principales.Length; i1++)
{
     //menus_principales[i1]. Con esto accedo a todas las propiedades que este contenga.
     MessageBox.Show("Menú Principal: " + menus_principales[i1].Name);

     flowLayout1 = menus_principales[i1].Controls.OfType<FlowLayoutPanel>().ToArray();
     categorias_menu = flowLayout1[0].Controls.OfType<Controles.MenuExpandible>().ToArray();

     for (int i2 = 0; i2 < categorias_menu.Length; i2++)
     {
          MessageBox.Show("Categoría: " + categorias_menu[i2].Name);

          flowLayout2 = categorias_menu[i2].Controls.OfType<FlowLayoutPanel>().ToArray();
          items = flowLayout2[0].Controls.OfType<LinkLabel>().ToArray();

          for (int i3 = 0; i3 < items.Length; i3++)
          {
               MessageBox.Show("Items: " + items[i3].Name);
          }
     }
 }
```

O a su vez utilizando ciclos `foreach` de esta manera:

```
foreach (var menu_principal in menus_principales)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Menú Principal: " + menu_principal.Name);

     flowLayout1 = menu_principal.Controls.OfType<FlowLayoutPanel>().ToArray();
     categorias_menu = flowLayout1[0].Controls.OfType<Controles.MenuExpandible>().ToArray();

     foreach (var categoria in categorias_menu)
     {
          MessageBox.Show("Categoría: " + categoria.Name);

          flowLayout2 = categoria.Controls.OfType<FlowLayoutPanel>().ToArray();
          items = flowLayout2[0].Controls.OfType<LinkLabel>().ToArray();

          foreach (var item in items)
          {
               MessageBox.Show("Item: " + item.Name);
          }
      }
 }
```

Saludos!...